Finding a list of four vectors in $F^3$ such that their span equals the following set...
Let $B = \{(x, y, z) \in F^3\mid  x + y + z = 0\}.$
One must find four vectors in $F^3$ such that their span equals set B. I chose these four vectors:
$$v_1 = (2, -2, 0),\\ 
v_2 = (0, 2, -2), \\
v_3 = (2, 0, -2), \\
v_4 = (2, 2, -4).$$
However, I believe these vectors are linearly dependant but I don't know how to show that is the case. I managed to show that that the span of the four vectors above is a subset of B, but got stuck trying to prove that B is a subset of the span of the four vectors. I attempted to take a $u$ $\in$ B where $u$ = (a, b, c) such that a + b + c = 0. I wanted to show that there is a linear combination of my four vectors that equal vector $u$, but when I tried finding this linear combination, I got a system of equations in which I couldn't find a solution. How can I prove that set B is a subset of the four vectors? Could I just replace the fourth vector with (0, 0, 0)?

Do you know a theorem of elementary Linear Algebra which guarantees that every $4$ vectors in $3$-dimensional space are linearly dependent?

$v3=v1+v2$ and $v4=v2+v3$

$v_1+v_2=(2,-2,0)+(0,2,-2)=(2,0,-2)=v_3$, and $v_1+2v_2=(2,-2,0)+2(0,2,-2)=(2,2,-4)=v_4$.

If you dont tell us more about $F,$ it is possible that $(2,-2,0)=(0,0,0).$ Specifically, if $F$ is a field of characteristic $2,$ that is, if $1+1=0.$

So my list is linearly dependent. Now I just need to figure out how to show that the span equals B. F can be either the set of real numbers or the set of complex numbers. It should not matter in the end result which of the two it is.

It is not clear why you'd choose examples with everything a multiple of $2,$ however, when making them $(1,-1,0)$ $(0,1,-1),\dots$ makes things simpler.

Specifically, $(x,y,z)=(x,-x-z,z)=x(1,-1,0)+(-z)(0,1,-1).$

Yes, I think that works. I didn't choose multiples of 2 for any particular reason. I can see how it does make it simpler though.
